# How to get input using the left-shift-bitwise operator?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

long scan()
{
    long int t = 0;
    char c;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
    while (c < '0' || c>'9')
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    while (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        **t = (t << 3) + (t << 1) + c - '0'; **
            c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return(t);
}

int main()
{
    int t, a[110], n, i; long long int c, sum;
    t = scan();
    while (t--)
    {
        sum = 0;
        scanf("%d%lld", &n, &c);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = scan();
            sum += a[i];
        }
        if (sum <= c) 
            printf("Yes\n");
        else 
            printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me understand the line in '**'. I know that left shift operator n multiplies the number by 2^n. So t is first getting multiplied by 8, then by 2. But how is that helping us get the input?

The scan() function gets the input and returns it.

Comment: Your code is C, not C++.  They are very different programming languages. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Consider using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -g yoursource.c -o yourbin`. Learn to use the [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger

Comment: BTW, I see no reason to use [getchar_unlocked(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar_unlocked.3.html) in *your* program. You want to use [getchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) and read more about [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)). You could read an entire line using [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) then learn about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques and [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

Comment: At last, I recommend using another name than `scan` which is looking like `scanf`. Choice of names is important

Answer (score 2):

The line you indicated with the asterisks doesn't help get input, all it does it update the value of the variable `t` based on the current value of `c`.

It is the calls to [getchar_unlocked()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar_unlocked) that get the next character from stdin and return it, and the program stores that value in the variable `c`.

The program expects that the characters will be numeric ASCII digits, so that the computed value of `(c-'0')` will be between 0 and 9 inclusive.  For each of those value values, it does the equivalent of `t = (t*8) + (t*2) + the_computed_value;` -- I'm not sure what the intent is, but that's what it's doing.

Comment: `(t*8 + t*2)` equals `t*10`, so it simply reads a decimal number from input while trying to optimize it as much as possible

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I'm not confident that that 'optimization' will result in any measurable speedup, though (at least not on a modern compiler or CPU).

Comment: According to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TtFW3m), gcc applies simillar optimization  with default settings and even more complicated optimization with `-O3`. So yes, that won't really affect performance.

Comment: As a general rule: Don't hinder your compiler to optimize by inventing doubtful optimizations. Source should be written for human readers in the first place. *Exceptions confirm the rule.*